Moving element from the list to the top of the screen in Flutter
Im interested in making a list of elements in which if I press any element it will expand and move to the top of the parent widget (in my case I use scaffold). In other words im looking for a way to make some visible element on the list become the first element among elements that user can currently see on the screen. I was searching for such method some time, but had a hard time finding something that will work exactly as I wish and was up to date. Thanks for any help.
